# Transition of Domination in the Universe

Tags: cosmology, radiation, matter

While deriving the epoch of matter-radiation equality, we assume the transition from radiation dominated universe to matter dominated universe as instantaneous. But how instantaneous is this transition really?

Comment: But you don't make that assumption at all.

Comment: Are there any examples anywhere where somebody makes "use" of the instantaneousness? As far as I know, the transition times are only used to argue that simpler models leaving out non-dominant contents are decent fits sufficiently before and after the transition.

Comment: Well, I found Andrew Liddle uses this assumption in his book "An Introduction to Modern Cosmology"- Second Edition, Ch-11. Quoting "We now have enough information to calculate the full temperature versus time relationship for the Universe, assuming an instantaneous transition between radiation domination and matter domination."

Comment: This is only useful if you have expressions such as $\rho \propto a^{-3(1+w)}$ and you want to plug in fixed $w$ for matter or radiation without taking its evolution into account. In an actual computation, on a computer, you would just do the integrals.